# Partition offset when mounting logical volume

Tags: filesystems, mount, partition, backup

I am maintaining a Linux-Server (Ubuntu 18.04 still) that, among other things, runs a virtual Windows 10 machine on it. The Windows machine uses a logical volume as its hard drive.

My goal is to backup certain files on the windows machine by mounting a snapshot of its LV in the host systems directory tree and then using rsync to backup the files (as I am doing for files on the Linux host system).

Here is what I was doing:

```
# create snapshot
lvcreate --snapshot --size 20G --name windows-backup /dev/vg0/vmachine

# mount snapshot
mkdir /mnt/windows-backup
mount --read-only /dev/vg0/windows-backup /mnt/windows-backup
```

However, the mounting failed with the following error message:

```
mount: /mnt/windows-backup: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg0-windows--backup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I suspected that's because the LV consists of multiple partitions and following the output of `fdisk -l /dev/vg0/windows-backup`

```
Disk /dev/vg0/windows-backup: 250 GiB, 268435456000 bytes, 524288000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6be134ed

Device                   Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/vg0/windows-backup1 *         2048   1126399   1124352  549M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/vg0/windows-backup2        1126400 523192612 522066213  249G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/vg0/windows-backup3      523194368 524283903   1089536  532M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
```

I then tried

```
mount --read-only --types ntfs -o offset=$((512*1126400)) /dev/vg0/windows-backup /mnt/windows-backup
```

which yielded the desired result.

**My question**: Can I somehow get rid of the step of having to manually lookup the partition offset prior to the mount, i.e. hard-coding the value in the backup script in my case. After all, this offset could theoretically (whereas unlikely) change?! Is there some way of dynamically determining the offset of the biggest NTFS partition?

Another thing that leaves me a bit puzzled is the fact that the first `mount` command (no offset, no specifying of the filesystem type) used to work some time ago without me changing the partition layout of the LV in the meantime. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to mount the device itself, but the partition(s) on it. The problem here is that system doesn't try to detect partitions on LVs by default (because it usually doesn't make sense to create partitions on top of LVs) so you first need to tell kernel to read the partition table using `partprobe /dev/vg0/windows-backup` and then mount `/dev/vg0/windows-backup2`.

It also might be a better idea to use some virtualization tools, like [libguestfs](https://libguestfs.org/) to access the data, instead of accessing the LV directly, I'm not really sure it's safe to access the data directly (but I'm not virtualization expert and you have a snapshot so it might be ok).